# How to put prefix for soap xml requests?

Tags: web-services, soap, prefix

I am making a web service call (in .Net 3.5). I want the Soap request to have namespace prefixes for the tags (the third-party web service needs them).

Current request:

```
<soap:Body> <GetBanksList xmlns="urn:QueryGroup"> ...
```

Desired request:

```
<soap:Body> <pfx:GetBanksList xmlns:pfx ="urn:QueryGroup"> ...
```

It seems I should use this attribute:

```
[XmlElementAttribute(Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
```

and specify my prefix, probably like this:

```
XmlSerializerNamespaces _namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces(
   new[] { new XmlQualifiedName("pfx", NS1) } );
```

What I can't find is where to put the attribute (I tried with the input params in Reference.cs) and where to specify the prefix!

Thanks for any help.